# Is there anyway to disable ctrl-click?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, click

I've been trying to play some games on my macbook (running on mojave) and whenever I try to hold CTRL and click it won't let me. Is there anyway to disable Ctrl-Click?

Comment: First check with command instead of control.

Answer (score 0):

`CTR-Click` is essentially right-clicking the mouse, and there is no way of remapping the keys without downloading 3rd party applications.

Karabiner can do this for you:
https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/

You can use it to map `CTR-Click` to left-click and it should work as you want it to.